# PHP visitorIP() returning localhost address

Tags: php, apache, nginx, geolocation, ip-address

I'm using the php code below to get the user's IP address in order to set their location. It works in our QA environment but in our prod environment, it always returns the IP as 127.0.0.1. I guess there must be some different Apache/Nginx (we use both) configuration between the two environments but I don't know what configuration would have an effect on this(?). The only other difference between the two environments would be that on our prod environment (hosted in the RackSpace cloud), traffic would first hit a load balancer... but I don't see why this would alter the IP to localhost so I don't believe that's the case - correct me if I'm wrong.

```
<?php 

$userIp = visitorIP();
$ipquad = explode(".", $userIp);
$ipnum = 16777216 * $ipquad[0] + 65536 * $ipquad[1] + 256 * $ipquad[2] + $ipquad[3];
var_dump('IP:- '.$userIp);
var_dump($ipquad);
var_dump('ipnum:- '.$ipnum);
die;

function visitorIP() {

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && urlIsPublic($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } 

    /* Check for Akamai custom header */
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_TRUE_CLIENT_IP'])){
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_TRUE_CLIENT_IP'];
    }   


    if (!(urlIsPublic(trim($ip)))) {
        if(defined('IP')) {
            return IP;
        }
    }

    return trim($ip);
}

function urlIsPublic($ip) {
    if(filter_var($ip,
                           FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,
                           FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE)
                !== false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

} 

?>
```

The output of var_dump($_SERVER) is below...

```
array(29) { ["APPLICATION_ENV"]=> string(10) "production" ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(19) "www.example.com" ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]=> string(32) "<MY_PUBLIC_IP>, 192.168.200.154" ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(5) "close" ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=> string(9) "max-age=0" ["HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"]=> string(1) "1" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(109) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36" ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(19) "gzip, deflate, sdch" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(26) "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6" ["PATH"]=> string(29) "/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin" ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(80) "
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at www.example.com Port 80
" ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(22) "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)" ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(19) "www.example.com" ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(37) "/var/www/vhosts/example/httpdocs" ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(14) "root@localhost" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(48) "/var/www/vhosts/example/httpdocs/ipinfo.php" ["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "45532" ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.0" ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(11) "/ipinfo.php" ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(11) "/ipinfo.php" ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(11) "/ipinfo.php" ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1493132187) }
```

Comment: On Prod, sounds a bit obvious, have you checked the content of $_SERVER to make sure what you're checking for is actually there ... You're load balancer may be sending it named differently, and also, can sometimes send multiple IPs to represent the proxies along the way...

Comment: For testing purposes, you can `var_dump($_SERVER)` and see if your IP is listed anywhere in there. You may need to check another variable, or the loadbalancer could be rewriting IPs.

Comment: `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is a comma separated list and/or one of your proxies may not be forwarding it.

Comment: @Brian, I'm now checking the value of $_SERVER using var_dump($_SERVER). I'm not sure what all the output means but I do see my public IP in it. I'll add the output of var_dump($_SERVER) above and maybe you can comment if you have any further advice.

Comment: @aynber see my last comment above. Output of var_dump($_SERVER) added to question. Thanks

Comment: Richard Smith has it right. If you look at `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, it's a comma separated list. Implode and trim, then check each individual IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a comma separated list, you need to check each individual IP:

```
function urlIsPublic($ip_list) {
    $ips = explode(',', $ip_list);
    foreach($ips as $ip) {
        $ip = trim($ip);
        if(filter_var($ip,
                FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,
                FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE)
            !== false) {
            return $ip;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then use it like this, and check if `$ip` is false later on:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = urlIsPublic($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
}
```